# Save canvas to image on server upon form submit with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canvas, camanjs

i'm using Caman JS to manipulate an image in my edit view for the model Item.

```
$('#vintage').click(function() {
  Caman("#preview_image", function () {
    this.reset();
    this.crossProcess(100)
    this.render(function () {
      this.addClass('selected');
    });
  });
});
```

Caman JS provides me with an option to get the base64 value of the Canvas object

```
var dataURL = this.toBase64();
```

However i'm now kind of stuck what to do with this information. Ideally i'd like to overwrite the original image upon submitting my rails form.

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found A solution. Here it is...

create a hidden field with the base64 data as the value

```
<input id="base64" type="hidden" value="" name="base64"/>
var dataURL = this.toBase64();
$('#base64').val(dataURL)
```

I then processed this in my controller.

```
unless params[:base64].empty?
  data =  params[:base64]
  image_data = Base64.decode64(data['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public#{@item.image.url.to_s}", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write image_data
  end
  // Carierwave method to regenerate thumbnails
  @item.image.recreate_versions!
end
```

Might help someone, I'm still definitely open to suggestions for better or more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: Mate! You just saved me so much heartache!